# Node Cassandra driver just hangs on execute()

Tags: node.js, cassandra

```
var cql = require('node-cassandra-cql');
var client = new cql.Client({hosts: ['*.*.*.*'], keyspace: '*', 
                             username:'*', password: '*'});

console.log('connected to ' , client);
console.log('Querying....');

client.execute('select * from example where field1=?', [1],
  function(err, result) {
    console.log('inside', result);

    if (err)
        console.log('execute failed',err);
    else
        console.log('got chat ' + result.rows[0].field1);

    client.shutdown();
  }
);
```

I am using this code, the execute() callbacks aren't getting called . To test I used an incorrect IP address, it immediately responds and this line console.log('execute failed',err) logs what is below.

```
execute failed { [PoolConnectionError]
  name: 'PoolConnectionError',
  info: 'Represents a error while trying to connect the pool, all the connections failed.',
  individualErrors:
   [ { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
         at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
         at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
       code: 'ENOTFOUND',
       errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
       syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
       hostname: '*.*.*.*'
       host: '*.*.*.*'
       port: 9042 } ] }
```

If with right IP address nothing happens may because new cql.Client internally calls connect (asynchronously) before even connection is made execute is attempted ? All perfectly works in CQLSH, my servers are in AWS US west coast.

Any inputs welcome.

Comment: What if you 'warm the pool', as recommended in the docs, with `client.connect([callback])`?

Comment: The doc says warming with connect is optional as it will be internally called. Quoting  "It ensures the pool is connected. It is not required to call it, internally the driver will call to connect when executing a query." I did try doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the legacy Cassandra driver `node-cassandra-cql`, as the [project readme states](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql#this-is-not-the-driver-you-are-looking-for), it is no longer maintained:

> node-cassandra-cql has graduated from community driver to being the
>   foundation of the official [Datastax Node.js Driver for Apache Cassandra](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql#this-is-not-the-driver-you-are-looking-for).
>
> There will be no more development in this repository. I encourage
>   everyone to start migrating to the new driver as soon as you can, it's
>   got some great new features that you should try out, along with an
>   improved cql to javascript type mapping for prepared statements.

Use [DataStax Node.js driver](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql#this-is-not-the-driver-you-are-looking-for) instead:

```
npm install cassandra-driver --save
```

Comment: Thanks got this from you as I posted the same issue in github. Sorry I should have paid more attention to the read-me.